# Javascript function joomla iframe auto height

Tags: javascript, function, iframe, joomla, height

i am hosting an iframe on my own domain and in joomla! i have set up an iframe wrapper.
the url i gave in started with `http://www.` and my settings are:

```
scroll bars: auto
width: 100%
height: 500

auto height: yes
auto add: no
```

both of my browsers give me a javascript error (null is not an object): using safari, firefox and chrome.
this error points to the script in the joomla core:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function iFrameHeight() {
    var h = 0;
    if (!document.all) {
        h = document.getElementById('blockrandom').contentDocument.height;
        document.getElementById('blockrandom').style.height = h + 60 + 'px';
    } else if (document.all) {
        h = document.frames('blockrandom').document.body.scrollHeight;
        document.all.blockrandom.style.height = h + 20 + 'px';
    }
}
</script>
```

this keeps my wrapper at 500px height and i want it to automatically be added according to the height of the iframe.

what can i replace this function with?
thanks in advance, laurent.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for resizing the iframe, all the elements that include the iframe should have set 100% height.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   function iSize(){
document.getElementById('mainFrame').height = document.getElementById('mainFrame').contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
document.getElementById('mainFrame').height = document.getElementById('mainFrame').contentDocument.documentElement.scrollHeight;
   }
});
</script>
```

1. Copy the file components/com_wrapper/views/wrapper/tmpl/default.php to
   templates/your_template/html/com_wrapper/wrapper/
2. Open the file templates/your_template/html/com_wrapper/wrapper/default.php
3. Replace the function iFrameHeight() with the new function below:

```
function pageY(elem) {
        return elem.offsetParent ? (elem.offsetTop + pageY(elem.offsetParent)) : elem.offsetTop;
    }
    var buffer = 0; //scroll bar buffer
    function iFrameHeight() {
        var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        height -= pageY(document.getElementById('blockrandom'))+ buffer ;
        height = (height < 0) ? 0 : height;
        document.getElementById('blockrandom').style.height = height + 'px';
    }
    document.getElementById('blockrandom').onload=iFrameHeight;
    window.onresize = iFrameHeight;
```

Comment: no, replacing the current function with yours does not work, and joomla does not allow you to enter percentage in the height field...

Comment: Did you rename the iframe to fit the function? 'mainFrame' is the iframe ID.

Comment: yes, and the console says: 'cant find variable `iFrameHeight`' (i tried changing function iSize to iFrameHeight, does nothing) and '`undefined` is not a function, evaluating `$(document).ready`'

Comment: Check my post edit, and another possible solution. Hope it helps.

Comment: okay, i fixed that by adding a few more pixels each, but now it makes all of my iframes very large

Comment: It would help if you gave us a link to your website.

Comment: i'm sorry but the website is private :(

Comment: The error: `'null' is not an object, evaluating 'document.getElementById('blockrandom').onload=iFrameHeight;`

Comment: but what is rather strange is that all of the browsers on my ipad display the frames perfectly...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23659/discussion-between-mrmadman-and-zefs)

Answer (score 0):

This code not work for me. But i resolved it that one:

```
var the_height = document.getElementById('blockrandom').contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
document.getElementById('blockrandom').style.height = the_height; //height + 'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry, correct line:
var the_height=document.getElementById('blockrandom').contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight; 
document.getElementById('blockrandom').height = the_height;

version ps: 1.6
version joomla: 3.2.1